# ScaledResolution is undefined

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

Could someone help me to get this fixed i am getting "The constructor ScaledResolution(Minecraft, int, int) is undefined"

```
import me.lucky.miner.Lucky;
import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiIngame;
import net.minecraft.client.gui.ScaledResolution;

public class HUD{
    
    public Minecraft mc = Minecraft.getMinecraft();
    
    public void draw() {
        
        ScaledResolution sr = new ScaledResolution(mc, mc.displayWidth, mc.displayHeight);
        
        
        mc.fontRendererObj.drawString(Lucky.Client_Name, 1, 1, 0xF5F5DC);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it was in the 1.7 (October 2013) release where [`ScaledResolution`](https://skmedix.github.io/ForgeJavaDocs/javadoc/forge/1.9.4-12.17.0.2051/net/minecraft/client/gui/ScaledResolution.html) changed so that it only takes a `Minecraft` object.

```java
public ScaledResolution(Minecraft minecraftClient)
    {
     ...
    }
```

Remove your int arguments, leaving only your `Minecraft` instance. If you are developing for a client version less than 1.7, consider updating as Forge does not maintain support for [legacy versions](https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/1.14.x/legacy/).

Comment: i am really new only one question, what should i write inside in there in the {} or tell me what i need to write in the contructor for ScaledResolution and what to change for " ScaledResolution sr = new ScaledResolution(mc, mc.displayWidth, mc.displayHeight);"

Comment: and i am using 1.8.8

Comment: You just need `ScaledResolution sr = new ScaledResolution(mc);`

Comment: and in the ScaledREsolution.java ?

Comment: because i dont get that mc.fontRendererObj.drawString("Name: " + Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer.getDisplayName(), 1, 1, 0xF5F5DC) in the hud